# PHP - Comparing Database DateTime with Current DateTime

Tags: php, database, datetime, mysqli

I've seen a few different DateTime comparisons on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to get it right. I need to be able to retrieve a row from the database, compare the DateTime with the current DateTime, and then evaluate whether or not it.

In this case, I need to check if the current row has expired or not.

```
if (strtotime(new DateTime()) > strtotime($row['expiration_date'])) {
  $response = 'Valid Coupon!';
} else {
  $response = 'Coupon Expired';
}
```

I've tried a few different ways, but none seem to work properly.

```
"2017-07-15 13:42:31 > 2017-07-15 14:27:31"
// and 
"2017-07-15 13:42:31 > 2017-07-14 13:03:04"
```

Both return as a Valid Coupon.

I've tried a number of things, but can't seem to figure out why these dates aren't working properly. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `->format`

```
 if (strtotime((new DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")) > strtotime($row['expiration_date'])) {
   $response = 'Valid Coupon!';
 } else {
    $response = 'Coupon Expired';
 }
```

Check this live : https://eval.in/833030

Or you can use

```
   (new DateTime())->getTimestamp();
```

Instead of

```
   strtotime((new DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

Check this : https://eval.in/833038

Answer (score 2):

You should change your `new DateTime()` and expatriation date and time into Unix timestamp.
When you convert your date into Unix timestamp, it will show in a number format. This way, you will compare your value.

For example:

```
$current_date = strtotime(new DateTime); //your current date and time 
$expatriation_date = strtotime($row['expiration_date']);  //your database data and time values // 
if($current_date > expatriation_date ){
    $response = 'Valid Coupon!';              
}
else{
    $response = 'Coupon Expired';
}
```

Your current date and time in Unix timestamp is "1500118951" and expatriation date and time in Unix timestamp is "1500121651". You can compare your value easily.

Comment: No. I think not. Because this is a easy way to find your solution. I have used this technique before.